# "Call to 'malloc' has an allocation size of 0 bytes" error when size is passed?

Tags: ios, c

I've seen there are questions about `malloc(0)` which yield this alert about allocation size. My question is that I am getting this alert *with* a size.

In my code:

- midiFileEventCount is of type `uint32_t`
- BASS_MIDI_EVENT is a `struct`

I get the alert on the line below. Before that line I check that `midiFileEventCount` is non-zero. My app seems to run correctly. Am I doing something wrong here?

This is on iOS 7.1

```
midiFileEvents=(BASS_MIDI_EVENT*)malloc(midiFileEventCount*sizeof(BASS_MIDI_EVENT));
```

Log statements:

```
printf("midiFileEventCount %u \n", midiFileEventCount);
printf("BASS_MIDI_EVENT size: %lu \n", sizeof(BASS_MIDI_EVENT));
printf("midiFileEvents size: %lu \n", midiFileEventCount*sizeof(BASS_MIDI_EVENT));
```

Output:

```
midiFileEventCount 1684 
BASS_MIDI_EVENT size: 20 
midiFileEvents size: 33680
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the line which produces the log message?

Comment: shouldn't midiFileEvents be of type pointer to struct BASS_MIDI_EVENT ?

Comment: @JesseRusak - that is the line XCode's Analyze function points to.

Comment: @codingBuddha - yes, good catch. That was a typo on my part - should have read `midiFileEventCount` Now fixed.

Comment: @TOMATO In the future, it would be helpful to explain exactly where you're seeing the error (when analyzing, in this case). Also, note that SO encourages posters to post a *complete, minimal program* that produces the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this is probably a potential bug in your code. The analyzer is telling you that there is a *possible* code path in your function in which the size is zero. Consider the following methods:

```
- (void *)foo:(int)size {
    return malloc(size);
}

- (void *)bar:(int)size {
    if (size == 0) {
        NSLog(@"got zero size!");
    }
    return malloc(size);
}
```

The first method will produce no analyzer results. The second will produce the same diagnostic you're seeing. The clang folks reason as follows: normally, a call to malloc will probably not have a zero size passed, so `foo` is unlikely to be a problem. `bar`, however, explicitly checks for a size of zero, and then continues to the malloc anyway. So, since you (the code writer) are clearly expecting that the size *might* be zero, it warns you that, in that case, you're mallocing zero bytes. (If you expand the diagnostic, it will show you exactly what assumptions it's making that are leading to a zero-sized allocation).

Of course, it's possible that you never actually call that method such that it produces a zero-sized malloc, but the analyzer only looks over smaller regions of code and notices "suspicious" patterns.

In the case of `bar` above, you could resolve it by asserting or returning NULL in the case that zero is passed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation- good answer. I removed my check `if (midiFileEventCount == 0)` and the alert went away. I had it there just for debugging purposes. I didn't realize the analyzer would check for that sort of condition.